# Wysihat jQuery fork can't add text to textarea

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wysihat

I use https://github.com/swilliams/jq-wysihat jQuery Wysihat fork. I ran `rake` to get the source code built, then copied the `dist/jq-wysihat.js` and `editor.css` over to my Rails library. It shows the Wysihat editor, and I can see that the `textarea` is hidden.

1. By right, whenever I type anything to the Wysihat, I should get the
   same text in the hidden `textarea` (seen using Firebug). This is the
   correct implementation I saw in 37signals Basecamp project. But, I
   don't see the `textarea` get filled with anything that I typed in
   the editor. What have I done wrong?
2. In the editing mode in my Rails app, how can I place the existing text into the Wysihat editor box?

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/80beans/wysihat-engine/wiki/installation

Answer (score 0):

Use this fork instead: https://github.com/mixonic/jq-wysihat

It seems to have a few more bug fixes in it. I had some problems running this in IE9 and it seemed to fix those too.